# echoing timestamp appends annoying "^@"

Tags: date, vim

i run this command `:echom system("date")<CR>` in vim.

my expected output is something like this: `Sat Jan 10 12:28:58 CET 2015`

but it always appends an annoying `^@`

so that the output is like this: `Sat Jan 10 12:28:58 CET 2015^@`

why?

and how can i easily avoid this?

when i run `date` in terminal it gives me the expected output. plus a newline of course (*1). so my guess is, that the `^@` comes from the newline, right?

i run vim 7.3 on debian (the version from the official repositories) in the terminal version, (not the gui version!) in a `gnome-terminal` with utf-8 encoding.

---

(*1): the prompt looks like this

```
user@host$ date
Sam Jän 10 12:28:58 CET 2015
user@host$
```

not like this:

```
user@host$ date
Sam Jän 10 12:28:58 CET 2015user@host$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^@` does come from the fact that `date` ends with a newline (`\n`).
You can either :

- remove the trailing characters (this will only output the expected result **if** the command ends with a newline) :

  `:echom system("date")[:-2]`
- substitute the trailing `\n` (a bit more verbose) :

  `:echom substitute(system("date"), '\n$', '', '')`